# print time between 10pm to 3am

Tags: php, codeigniter, time, timestamp, do-while

I have 2 time strings as below:

```
10pm
3am
```

I want to print the time between above-given string like:

```
10pm
11pm
12am
1am
2am
3am
```

PHP Code I tried:

```
<?php
$new_otime = strtotime(date('H:i',strtotime('10pm')));
$close_time = strtotime(date('H:i',strtotime("3am")));
do { ?>
<option value="<?php echo date("g a",$new_otime) ?>"><?php echo date("g a",$new_otime); ?></option>
<?php
$new_otime = $new_otime+=3600;                      
} while ($new_otime == $close_time);
?>
```

But it echoes only 10 pm in the select box. How can I echo all the time between those string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest some work around to make this work:

```
<?php
$new_otime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime(date('Y-m-d').' 10pm')));
$close_time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime(date('Y-m-d').' 3am')));
if($close_time < $new_otime){
  $close_time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime(date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+1 day')).'3am')));
}
do { ?>
<option value="<?php echo date("g a",$new_otime) ?>"><?php echo date("g a",$new_otime); ?></option>
<?php
$new_otime = $new_otime+=3600;                      
} while ($new_otime <= $close_time);
?>
```

1. Check if end time is bigger
2. If not make it next day
3. Loop while `new_otime` is less than `close_time`

Comment: it will go to infinite loop

Comment: Problem is that `10pm` is already bigger than `3am`, so it won't loop

Comment: yes, but i want to print times between those. any idea?

Comment: How can i change this `$close_time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime(date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+1 day')).'3am')));` **3 am** to dynamic in this line?

Comment: So just put variable with your value instead of `'3am'`

Answer (score 2):

You could also try using DateTime and DatePeriod:

```
$from = date_create_from_format('ha', '10pm');
//create 5 interations, each adds an additional hour
$dp = new DatePeriod($from, new DateInterval('PT1H'), 5);

/** @var DateTime $d */
foreach ($dp as $d) {
    echo $d->format('ha');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
$time=22;
for($i=0;$i<6;$i++) {
echo date("g a",mktime($time+$i,0,0,09,21,2016))."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$new_otime = "10pm";
$close_time = "3am";
$counter=0;
while(date("g a",strtotime($new_otime)+3600*$counter)<=date("g a",strtotime($close_time))){
     echo date("g a",strtotime($new_otime)+3600*$counter).'<br>';
     $counter++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    <?php
    $new_otime = "10pm";
    $close_time = "3am";
    $new_otime = strtotime(date_create_from_format("ha", $new_otime)->format("ha"));
    $close_time = strtotime(date_create_from_format("ha", $close_time)->format("ha"));
        do {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo date("ha", $new_otime) ?>"><?php echo date("ha", $new_otime); ?></option>
            <?php
            $new_otime = strtotime(date("ha", strtotime("+1 hours", $new_otime)));
        } while ($new_otime != $close_time);
        if ($new_otime == $close_time) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo date("ha", $new_otime) ?>"><?php echo date("ha", $new_otime); ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
```